# API stops working after a while

Tags: python, linux, postgresql, pandas, bottle

I wrote an API that takes a directory as an input and it will load every text file (.txt) inside that folder (and its sub-folders) into a Postgres DB.

The API works for a few files (around 3) but when it gets down to "reading" the fourth file, regardless of the file, the program crashes. I even separated the files into chunks of three and the API stopped anyway. This is the error I get:

```
ERROR:tornado.application:Uncaught exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rvelez/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/http1connection.py", line 237, in _read_message
    delegate.finish()
  File "/home/rvelez/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/httpserver.py", line 230, in finish
    self.request_callback(self.request)
  File "/home/rvelez/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/wsgi.py", line 276, in __call__
    WSGIContainer.environ(request), start_response)
  File "/home/rvelez/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bottle.py", line 979, in __call__
    return self.wsgi(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/rvelez/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bottle.py", line 954, in wsgi
    out = self._cast(self._handle(environ))
  File "/home/rvelez/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bottle.py", line 862, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "/home/rvelez/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bottle.py", line 1740, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "my_api_clientes_cuentas.py", line 63, in read_txt
    index=False)
  File "/home/rvelez/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1534, in to_sql
    chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
  File "/home/rvelez/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site- packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 473, in to_sql
    chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
  File "/home/rvelez/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1156, in to_sql
    table.insert(chunksize)
  File "/home/rvelez/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 670, in insert
    self._execute_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
  File "/home/rvelez/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 645, in _execute_insert
    conn.execute(self.insert_statement(), data)
  File "/home/rvelez/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 948, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/rvelez/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 269, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/rvelez/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1060, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/home/rvelez/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1200, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/home/rvelez/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1416, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/rvelez/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 187, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/rvelez/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1170, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/home/rvelez/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 683, in do_executemany
    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
  File "/home/rvelez/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/encodings/utf_8.py", line 15, in decode
    def decode(input, errors='strict'):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I also get a `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

This is the code:

```
@apiR2A.route('/api/lectura', method=['POST'])
def read_txt():
    #get_postgres_connection()
    arch = [] #list of succesfully read files
    arch_err = [] #list of files with errors
    con = create_connection() #creating connection with db
    archivos = request.query.archivos
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(archivos):
        for file in files: #looping through all the files inside root
            if file.endswith(".txt"): #only looking for text files
                #creating dataframe
                df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root, file), encoding="utf-8", sep="|", header=None) 
                if len(df.columns) is not 12: #verifying num of columns
                    print("WARNING: File {} has wrong format\n".format(os.path.join(root, file)))
                    arch_err.append(file)
                    continue
                sleep(10)
                df.columns = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"] #setting column names
                print('Reading: {}'.format(os.path.join(root, file)))
                #adding df to db
                df.to_sql('FBDClientesCuentas',
                      con,
                      if_exists='append',
                      index=False)
                print('{} succesfully added to db.\n'.format(file))
                sleep(5)
                arch.append(file)

    if len(arch) > 0:
        print('Files loaded to database:')
        for x in arch:
            print(x)

    if len(arch_err) > 0:
        print('\nUnread files:')
        for x in arch_err:
            print(x)
```

EDIT: I ommited what seemed to be the root of the problem, the way the API was run was as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    apiR2A.run( server='tornado', host='0.0.0.0', port=3000, reloader=True)
```

The issue was with the server I chose to run the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the server from Tornado to Paste, the API was able to load all the files into the database without any issues.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    apiR2A.run( server='paste', host='0.0.0.0', port=3000, reloader=False)
```